How to simulate integer numbers between1 and 5 with exact mean and sd in R or python
I want to simulate data with integer value  and exact desirable mean and sd. I know how to generate floating numbers with exact mean and sd. And then round it to have integer values but the sd and mean change after rounding!
`mu <- 3
sigma <- 1.5
N <- 100
sims <- round(rnorm(N, mu, sigma),0)`

If you're simulating, then it's very unlikely that your observed mean and std deviation will match exactly the population mean and std dev, even without rounding.  That's the nature of random data.  If you MUST have exactly the mean and std deviation you specify, then generate n-2 random observations and then solve two simultaneous equations to give you the desired mean and std dev you require.  But if you're rounding to integers that's almost certainly going to be impossible.  If you're not rounding, then, IMHO, what you are attempting is almost certainly misguided.

Ignore the "in R or python" aspect of this question - ask yourself how this is possible mathematically.

.. and, if you want integer data, why are you using rnorm in the first place?

I’m voting to close this question because the OP's intent is not mathematically feasible.

You want to simulate 100 integers between 1 and 5 such that the mean is 5 and the sd is 5??

Equivalently, you are trying to generate a set of numbers with given (sum) and given (sum of squares). Create the collection of these (a non-trivial task!) and then choose one of those at random.

I edited the question. I actually did not want to get the sd=5 and mean =5!
just wrote a sample code to tell what I am using to generate my arrays!

You won't be able to restrict the values of the random variable to be between 1 and 5 and still get a mean of 5 and a standard deviation of 5. Without that restriction there are an infinite number of integer distributions that result in a mean of 5 and a standard deviation of 5. One example:
x <- sample(c(0L, 10L), 1e8, 1)
mean(x)
#> [1] 5.000759
sd(x)
#> [1] 5

For a more general solution, we could use, e.g., a shifted Poisson mixture distribution. The function fGetDist below returns a function that will return samples from a shifted Poisson mixture distribution that has the specified mean and standard deviation.
fGetDist <- function(mu, sigma) {
  sigma <- sigma^2
  s <- as.integer(ceiling(mu - sigma))
  mu0 <- mu - s
  d <- sqrt(sigma - mu0)
  lambda <- c(mu0 - d, mu0 + d)
  function(n) rpois(n, sample(lambda, n, 1)) + s
}

Example usage:
# mean = 5, sd = 5
x <- fGetDist(5, 5)(1e7)
range(x)
#> [1] -15  35
mean(x)
#> [1] 5.002506
sd(x)
#> [1] 4.999406

# mean = -sqrt(2), sd = pi
x <- fGetDist(-sqrt(2), pi)(1e7)
range(x)
#> [1] -11  18
mean(x)
#> [1] -1.414594
sd(x)
#> [1] 3.140949

# mean = 0, sd = 1
x <- fGetDist(0, 1)(1e7)
range(x)
#> [1] -1  8
mean(x)
#> [1] -0.0004761
sd(x)
#> [1] 0.9996251

